# Getting error for TSLint in response of ng lint even after migrating from TSLint to ESLint and uninstalling the TSLint as well

Tags: angular, eslint, typescript-eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, angular.json

I have just migrated from TSLint to ESLint and uninstalled the TSLint. But after running the ng lint command in terminal, the error displayed is - Ensure TSLint is installed.

Following is a snippet of few lines I get after running the command ng lint:-

Lint warnings found in the listed files.

Lint errors found in the listed files.

**Linting "cat-e2e"...**
**An unhandled exception occurred: Unable to find TSLint. Ensure TSLint is installed.**

See "C:\Users\VISHAK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-PWse7M\angular-errors.log" for further details.

I think the issue is in my angular.json file because **I still see some traces of tslint in it**
Please find below my angular.json file:-

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "cat": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/Web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
              "node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "src/ngsw-config.json",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "cat:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "cat:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "cat:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
              "node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/Web.config"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "cat-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "cat:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "cat",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

I have no idea what to try. My angular version is 8.